# What is a REST API?

Tags: rest, api

I don't understand why suddenly there is this term "REST API". As far as I've understood it means "The client requests some sort of representation of a state". Thus, every server in the world that serves HTML pages is suddenly a "REST API"?? The state is the content of the URL and the representation is the HTML code, right? That's the oldest thing in the world, I request a resource and I get the resource. Why is this suddenly a REST API or am I not understanding something subtle here? Also when I connect to an SQL Server and say "SELECT * FROM client_table" I get the state (the content of the table?) from this request. The form of representation could be a dataframe which I use to contain the received data. Again, I just request data and I get the data, is this suddenly a REST API too? To me everything is a REST API, networking itself is always REST API: request data -> get data. I feel like there must be something subtle that I don't understand and I cannot define what it is? Why does this term exist?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer

Comment: Check out this Question and the top answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming

Comment: _Hypermedia_ is possibly the answer you are looking for. The term _REST_ was created by Roy T. Fielding and such architectural style is defined in the [chapter 5](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) of his dissertation.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand why suddenly there is this term "REST API"

It's not particularly sudden; the development of REST begins in [roughly 1994](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/evaluation.htm); the contrast of REST with other approaches (SOAP, XML-RPC) goes back to the early part of this millennium.

[image: Randall Munroe's comic explaining that there are thousands of people learning things that "everyone knows" every day]

> every server in the world that serves HTML pages is suddenly a "REST API"?

Yes, that's *exactly* right.  The world wide web is the reference application for the REST architectural style, and it was catastrophically successful -- we're able to do amazing things using general purpose components that respect shared, well-documented standards.

> when I connect to an SQL Server... is this suddenly a REST API too?

No, it is not.

> I feel like there must be something subtle that I don't understand and I cannot define what it is?

Fielding described the [REST architectural style](https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm) in his thesis, that's the place to start.  The key ideas to pay attention to: caching, and the uniform interface.  IT would also be good to review what he had to say about [hypermedia](https://roy.gbiv.com/untangled/2008/rest-apis-must-be-hypertext-driven).

> Why does this term exist?

Historically, as a shorthand to distinguish *resource* oriented approaches to others.

For instance, in the late 90s, REST stood in contrast to SOAP and XML/RPC, which used HTTP as dumb transport.  Similarly, in 2006(ish), folks were noticing that out of the box Rails was procedure oriented, rather than resource oriented.

In other words, REST was a sort of shorthand for "I do not like Thing.  It should be more like the world wide web."